# how to install light package in python?

Tags: python-3.6

When I am installing light package in python 3.6.5 by using the command

```
pip install light
```

I am getting this error:

```
Collecting light
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/e5/78270f0aec7135793a85d4898b0075b741f7e2041011c24d8af76c9a3671/light-0.0.1.tar.gz
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Bhanu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p6x112xj\light\setup.py", line 43, in <module>
        with open(os.path.join(thisdir, "requirements.txt"), "r") as f:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Bhanu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-p6x112xj\\light\\requirements.txt'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Bhanu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p6x112xj\light\
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3 then you need to use pip3 to install packages unless you have activated a virtual environment with python 3

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that project is not anymore maintained.

- https://pypi.org/project/light/
- https://github.com/riga/light (leads to a 404 page)

If you download the entire source from pypi ([light-0.0.1.tar.gz](https://pypi.org/project/light/#files)), untar it to a *light-0.0.1* directory, and check *setup.py*, there's a part of the code that's looking for a *requirements.txt* file:

```
 42 install_requires = []
 43 with open(os.path.join(thisdir, "requirements.txt"), "r") as f:
 44     install_requires.extend(line.strip() for line in f.readlines() if line.strip())
 45
```

But it's obvious that *requirements.txt* does not exist:

```
|- light
|- light.egg-info
|- PKG-INFO
|- setup.cfg
|- setup.py
```

You can try creating a blank *requirements.txt* file in the same directory or commenting-out those lines from *setup.py* that's looking for *requirements.txt*:

```py
install_requires = []
#with open(os.path.join(thisdir, "requirements.txt"), "r") as f:
#    install_requires.extend(line.strip() for line in f.readlines() if line.strip())
```

Then install the package manually:

```
$ cd <path/to/light-0.0.1>
$ pip3 install .
```

It's going to install successfully.

Though, I would suggest staying away from this package as it looks like it's not maintained anymore or isn't ready yet for a production release.